# Saving Python .txt file to user's desktop without stating my user name in code

Tags: python

I'd like to create a .txt file which will be saved to the desktop of whoever's running this code. My current solution specifies the path to *my own* particular desktop and includes my username. How should I modify the code so that it works with any user?

```
filename = open('c:/Users/my_username/Desktop/filename.txt', 'w')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.expanduser('~')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) for a platform independent way of automatically expanding a user's home directory, so in practice it might look like:

```py
with open(
    os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'filename.txt'), 'w'
) as fh:
    # do things
```

Answer (score 1):

C.Nivs provides an excellent Answer, but what if the Desktop is not located in the home directory? my current Work and Home desktop, both running Windows 10 have the Desktop nested under OneDrive or DropBox.

Lets look at a possible solution using Pathlib using the `relative_to` method to measure the distance from the home directory and return the minimum. We will use a recursive method to look over our directory and search for a `Desktop` Match.

## In Action

```
path_finder()
out:
WindowsPath('C:/Users/datanovice/OneDrive/Desktop')
```

The dictionary it self will look like this :

```
{WindowsPath('C:/Users/datanovice/anaconda3/Library/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop'): 7,
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/datanovice/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0/Library/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop'): 9,
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/datanovice/AppData/Local/Microsoft/PlayReady/Internet Explorer/Desktop'): 6,
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/datanovice/AppData/Local/Microsoft/PlayReady/Internet Explorer/InPrivate/Desktop'): 7,
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/datanovice/OneDrive/Desktop'): 2}
```

---

For your use case it will be similair to C.Nivs solution:

```
with open(
    pathfinder().joinpath('filename.txt'), 'w'
) as fh:
```

---

## Function & Module.

```
from pathlib import Path

def path_finder(directory=Path.home()):

    path_finder_dict = {}

    for child in Path.home().rglob('*'):
        if child.name == 'Desktop':
            distance = len(child.relative_to(Path.home()).parts)

            path_finder_dict[child] = distance

    return min(path_finder_dict, key=path_finder_dict.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `getpass` library which gets the current active user, then replace this with the username:

```
import getpass
filename = open('C:/Users/'+getpass.getuser()+'/Desktop/filename.txt', 'w')
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the expanduser method in os.path...

> os.path.expanduser('[username you want]')